# Android 2.1 - Object Detection on OpenCV 2.0 and image's quality of different devices.

Tags: android, c, opencv

Now, I'm working on a project about object detection using opencv on Android 2.1. 
And I have many problems:

1. I cannot use the lastest version of opencv on Android 2.1 project, And now I use Opencv 2.0 written on C-language. I see many function like haarcascade or image process is missed or haved many bug:(
2. Each android device give me a different image's quality. So, it make a detection module give wrong result. For example: HTC Desire give me a darken image, Sony Arc give me a image have more blue or yellow value etc... How can I process these image to same quality for training and detecting.
3. When I run haartraining command (on opencv 2.0), with npos = 20, nneg = 10, It never is successful, even if I run it more than 24 hours. 
   Today is deadline of my project. 
   http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/object_detection.html 
   Thanks so much for your supports.